# ‘numeric_limits’ was not declared in this scope, no matching function for call to ‘max()’

Tags: c++, max, cin, numeric-limits

I compiled this code at home on my mac w/ xcode and there was no provblem. I compile it at school with g++ on linux and I get these errors:

> numeric_limits’ is not a member of std
>
> expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
>
> no matching function for call to ‘max()’

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int GetIntegerInput(int lower, int upper)
{
    int integer = -1;
    do
    {
        cin >> integer;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');  //errors here
    } while (integer < lower || integer > upper);

    return integer;
}
```

I'm guessing maybe I have to include an extra header. If I take away the `std::` it just gives me a similar error:

`numeric_limits` was not declared in this scope

Comment: When you read the documentation for `numeric_limits` to learn how to use it, didn't it tell you what header it's in?

Comment: yeah, but that was a while ago, and then I just recently copy pasted the code from my other project without realizing.

Comment: add `#include <limits>`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You need to include the header file `<limits>`, which is where `std::numeric_limits` is defined.  Your Mac compiler was helping you out by automatically including that header file; however, you should not rely on that behavior and explicitly include any header files you need.

Comment: Is there a name for this feature?  I want to figure out how to disable it so I don't break platform independence.

Answer (score 13):

GCC 11 started to explicitly require including `<limits>`, `<memory>`, `<utility>`, `<thread>` according to https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-11/porting_to.html#header-dep-changes

The same or similar story is with Clang 12 (or earlier, I don't know).

Since I meet this error (often) while using `yarn` (package manager for Node.js) and it overwrites all source files every time, I cannot add `#include <limits>` easily: I would need either to fork or spam `cp /tmp/fixedBad.h /installdir/bad.h` while compilation is ongoing.

Therefore my solution is to add to CXXFLAGS (not CFLAGS) this:

`-include /usr/include/c++/11/limits` (Ubuntu 21.04, gcc 11.1.0)

`-include /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/limits` (Arch Linux; same version but path differs from Debian/Ubuntu)

or elegantly: `-include /usr/include/c++/11*/limits`

Note that `*` works only when used by shell (bash, sh, zsh, etc.) or a makefile. In other words, gcc and clang don't pay attention to `*` in file paths, so beware if you use `ninja build` or directly pass arguments to gcc/clang from e.g. a C program.

I have this in `/etc/environment`

```
#CPPFLAGS="-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -DNDEBUG"
CPPFLAGS="-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2"
CFLAGS="-g -pipe -march=native -mtune=native -Ofast -pipe -ftree-vectorize -fstack-protector-strong"
CXXFLAGS="-g -pipe -march=native -mtune=native -Ofast -pipe -ftree-vectorize -fstack-protector-strong -include /usr/include/c++/11*/limits"
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro"
RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=native -C opt-level=2"
```

Check `echo $CXXFLAGS`, and if changes aren't applied, restart shell or OS, or logout of the current tty, or switch to another tty, or just run in terminal:

```
export CXXFLAGS="-g -pipe -march=native -mtune=native -Ofast -pipe -ftree-vectorize -fstack-protector-strong -include /usr/include/c++/11*/limits"
```

or `set -a; source /etc/environment; set +a;`

I also tried adding to CXXFLAGS `-include '<limits>'` and `-include '<limits.h>'`, but it says "No such file or directory"

Also I have another solution (very dirty):

Add this to `/usr/include/stdint.h` (or `stdlib.h` or some other popular file) before the last line (`#endif`):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C++" {
       #include <limits>
}
#endif
```

Ubuntu 21.04's and Debian Buster's `dpkg-query -S /usr/include/stdlib.h`
says it is owned by `libc6-dev:amd64`. Arch Linux's `pacman -Qo /usr/include/stdlib.h` says it is owned by `glibc`. So this hack will be overwritten when the package updates, don't forget.

Comment: `-include limits` and even `-includelimits` seem to work.